# How to read values inside a tag using STAX parser in JAVA

Tags: java, xml-parsing, stax

I have a xml like below.

```
<user VERSION_NO="1">
<userCompany QTAG="30000-9" LITERAL="Pharmaxy Group" CA_ID="33">PG</userCompany></user>
```

where "user " is my parent USER DTO and in the DTO I have attributes like "userCompany".

I am hitting a webservice(soap) , where I get the response as above. Based on the "Literal" value I need to do perform some business logic and set to my USER DTO.

So how to read the "LITERAL" value using STAX ?

Answer (score 1):

At first you needs to know some technical terms. In `XML` your `userCompany` is an element while `LITERAL` is an attribute of that element.

Using `StAX` you first get a reader from [XMLInputFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLInputFactory.html). I prefer `XMLEventReader`. This reader is able iterating over all `XML` elements in given `XML`. If you have found the wanted [StartElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/events/StartElement.html) - `userCompany` in your case - then you can get the value of the attribute named "LITERAL" from it.

For naming `XML` elements and attributes `QName`s are used istead of simply `String`s. This is because `QName` is able taking different name spaces into account.

Example:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.xml.stream.*;
import javax.xml.stream.events.*;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

public class StAXGetAttributeValue {

 static String getAttributeValue(StartElement startElement, QName attributeName) {
  Attribute attribute = startElement.getAttributeByName(attributeName);
  String attributeValue = attribute.getValue();
  return attributeValue;
 }

 public static void main (String args[]) throws Exception {

  String xmlString = "<user VERSION_NO=\"1\"><userCompany QTAG=\"30000-9\" LITERAL=\"Pharmaxy Group\" CA_ID=\"33\">PG</userCompany></user>";

  XMLEventReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLEventReader(new StringReader(xmlString));
  while (reader.hasNext()) {
   XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
   if(event.isStartElement()) {
    StartElement startElement = (StartElement)event;
    QName startElementName = startElement.getName();  
    if("userCompany".equals(startElementName.getLocalPart())) {
     String valueOf_LITERAL_Attribute = getAttributeValue(startElement, QName.valueOf("LITERAL"));
     System.out.println(valueOf_LITERAL_Attribute); //prints Pharmaxy Group
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```